# First dispatch() for job disappears

Tags: laravel

My setup:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Laravel 5.6
- PHP 7.2.4
- MySQL 5.7.22

I have a very weird situation with queues. I have set up the database as queue driver but when I use the `tinker` console to test dispatching of jobs, the first job always disappears: It's not in the `jobs` table, it's not in the `failed_jobs` table, and there's nothing in the logs as well. The problem is there every time I start a fresh session of `tinker`. If I repeat the dispatch a second, third, foruth time, etc., everything works as it should.

Here's a simple job I've defined:

```
class AddToList implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        Log::info('List updated!');
        return; // temporarily added for testing

        // . . . other code
    }
```

and in tinker I do:

```
>>> \App\Jobs\AddToList::dispatch([])->onQueue('default')->delay(now());
=> Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\PendingDispatch {#2312}
```

and there's nothing, like I described above. And if I do this a second time:

```
>>> \App\Jobs\AddToList::dispatch([])->onQueue('default')->delay(now());
=> Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\PendingDispatch {#2315}
```

the job appears in the `jobs` table and gets processed as desired.

Anyone faced something similar?

Comment: have you found the solution to this by any chance? I'm having the same issue with beanstalkd and it's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

I just fell for it -again- myself, so I will answer this in case anyone runs into the same issue.

Tinker keeps the `PendingDispatch` object in memory until the next command is evaluated. Since the `PendingDispatch`es are finally executed upon their destruction, it never reaches the job queue until then.

So, if you are dispatching the job a second time, it seemingly works - and keeps working, but in reality it will always be the *previous* job you see in your queue, not the one you just dispatched.

### Working around the issue

You could prepend a second statement after the dispatch call, either on the same line or a second one:

```php
>>> App\Jobs\MyJob::dispatch();1;
=> 1
```

```php
>>> App\Jobs\MyJob::dispatch()
=> Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\PendingDispatch {#4977}
>>> 1
=> 1
```

See here for a helpful issue on that case:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/23167#issuecomment-569860608

Answer (score 0):

Assign it to a variable, like this:

```
$dispatched = \App\Jobs\AddToList::dispatch([])->onQueue('default')->delay(now());
```